# DRF Serializer doesn't recieve value from request for ManyToMany field

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

My Model is

```
class ChatRoom(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=55, verbose_name='Имя чата', unique=True)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(
        CustomUser, 
        verbose_name='Пользователи', 
        related_name='user_chatrooms', 
        null=True
    )
```

My Serializer for this model

```
class ChatRoomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    users = UserInfoSerializer(many=True, read_only=False)
    class Meta:
        model = ChatRoom
        fields = [
            'name',
            'users'
        ]
```

View looks

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def api_create_chat(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = ChatRoomSerializer(data=request.data)
        data = {}
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I do request (here is body)

```
<QueryDict: {'name': ['benny'], 'users': ['11,1']}>
```

In this case I recieve Error

```
{'users': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')]}
```

And I can't understand what is wrong here.
When I change parameter to `read_only=True` in `UserInfoSerializer` it works, but it doesn't add user to new Chat object.

```
{
    "name": "benny",
    "users": []
}
```

**UPD**
I tried to add `create()` method, but it didn't help

```
    def create(self, validated_data):
      users = validated_data.pop('users')
      users = [int(id) for id in users.split(',')]
      chat_instance = ChatRoom.objects.create(name=validated_data.pop('name'))
      for id in users:
          chat_instance.users.add(CustomUser.objects.get(pk=id))
      return chat_instance
```

**UPD 2**
`UserInfoSerializer`

```
class UserInfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['id',]
```

Comment: Try to add users like this inside your serializer ```users = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)```

Comment: You didn't  provided **UserInfoSerializer**

Comment: If I use `users = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)` I got `KeyError: 'users'` because `read_only=True`.

Comment: Maybe I do wrong request, but it doesn`t look like wrong one. Strange that serializer doesn't see 'users' at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by modifying `serializer` in `view.py`. It isn't good decision, but it works.

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def api_create_chat(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = ChatRoomSerializer(data=request.data)
        data = {}
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            users_id = [int(id) for id in request.data['users'].split(',')]
            chat = ChatRoom.objects.get(pk=serializer.data['id'])
            for id in users_id:
                user = CustomUser.objects.get(pk=id)
                chat.users.add(user)
                serializer.data['users'].append({'user': user.id, 'username': user.username})
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: I also deleted `create()`